# JQuery to hide items in a ListBox

Tags: jquery

I have an .aspx page that contains a ListBox, ID="lstAvailRates".  I'm trying to hide these by default using JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{$('#lstAvailRates').hide();
});
```

This works, but the results are not desirable.  I want to keep the ListBox and hide the items.  The above hides the entire ListBox.

MC

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#lstAvailRates').find('option').hide();
});
```

Finds the option element from a select and hides them. Just change the argument for 'find' to whichever elements within the #1stAvailRates element you want to hide.

Comment: could be also shortened to: $('#lstAvailRates li').hide(); or $('li', #lstAvailRates').hide(); if this makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#lstAvailRates li').hide();
});
```

The `selector` serach for a element with the tag `li` which belongs to a element with `ID` lstAvailRates

```
<ul id="lstAvailRates">
 <li>This will be hidded</li>
 <li>This will be hidded</li>
 <li>This will be hidded</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

A list box is a `select` according to Wikipedia.
So you have to do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#lstAvailRates').find('option').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Listbox will be rendered as an HTML select element in the browser.

This will hide all elements in the select except the first option. Assuming you have the "Select any is the first" option and you want to keep that.

```
$(function(){

    $("#lstAvailRates option").each(function(){        
       $(this).hide(); 
    });    

});​
```

working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/PBzuQ/7/